# Subquery issue (SQL)

Tags: sql, subquery

I am facing a challenge with a SQL query.
Basically I would like to retrieve the registers which present a [Start] later than their respective [Outgoing tasks].

The table looks like this:

```
Main Project    Main Link    Name         Start            Outgoing tasks
A               1            A1           02.01.2012       A2   
A               1            A2           01.01.2012       A3
```

...

The query I wrote is this one:

```
SELECT [Name], [Start], [Outgoing tasks] 
FROM [Sheet1$] 
WHERE [Main project] = 'A' 
AND [Main link] = '1' 
AND [Outgoing tasks] IS NOT NULL 
AND [Start] > (SELECT [Start] 
        FROM [Sheet1$] 
        WHERE [Main project] = 'A' 
        AND [Main link] = '1' 
        AND [Name] =  [Outgoing tasks])
```

It doesn't return any error, however it simply doesn't bring the expected results.

Do you guys know what might be wrong?
Any support is very appreciated!!!

Further info:

This table comes from a MS Project like application. So we have a milestone, its data, successor and predecessor. What I actually need is a list of milestones which have a start date later than its successor (Which is an error in the project management perspective). So if A1.Start > A2.Start, then i should appear in the results. Let me know if you need any further detail.

Comment: Yes, I am actually querying from an Excel file.

Comment: Does the subquery act independent or it will always try to compare with the main query?

Comment: Depends. If you want it to be executed once per main query row you need to correlate it; that is, to add criteria referencing column(s) from main query. You probably need to qualify `Name` or `Outgoing task`. Could you please tell us what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Nikola. Thanks for your support. This table comes from a MS Project like application. So we have a milestone, its data, successor and predecessor. What I actually need is a list of milestones which have a start date later than its successor (Which is an error in the project management perspective). So if A1.Start > A2.Start, then i should appear in the results. Let me know if you need any further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 select t1.* from [$Sheet1] t1
      inner join [$Sheet1] t2
           on t1.[main project] = t2.[main project]
           and t1.[main link] = t2.[main link]
           and t1.[outgoing tasks] = t2.name
           and t1.start>t2.start
```

Comment: It seems good, but it brought all issues. I actually want just the issues for the project A and main link 1. Shall I subquery it or is there a way to include the parameters?

Comment: Just add a `where t1.[main project]='a' ...` etc

Comment: Thanks! before or after the inner join? :D I am noob :(

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be a correlated sub-query, you need a way to refer to the outer statement's table inside the inner query. In MySQL you'd do it like this:

```
SELECT name, start, outgoing_tasks FROM sheet1 foo WHERE main_project = 'A' AND main_link = '1' AND outgoing_tasks IS NOT NULL AND start > (SELECT start FROM sheet1 bar WHERE main_project = 'A' AND main_link = '1' AND bar.name = foo.outgoing_tasks);
```

Notice that I give the outer query's table an alias of `foo` and the inner query's table the alias of `bar`. Then I can refer to the outer table in the `WHERE` predicate of the nested (inner) query: `... AND bar.name = foo.outgoing_tasks ...`

Comment: Hi Paul, unfortunately it didn't work. For an unknown reason the application crashes. (I made sure to use the correct naming). Thanky anyway

Comment: The syntax I gave you was for MySQL, you probably needed to change syntax to suit your environment, wrap the field names in brackets and so on. Not to worry, you got your answer on this. :)